# Time series order in plotly R

Tags: r, timestamp, time-series, plotly

EDIT: 
Right now, the values in x axis are characters, not timestamps, sorry for the confusion. I just want the strings to be plotted from 1 to length(df$time) and the corresponding y values.

I am trying to plot a time series data in plotly. The x axis is character variable, with time stamps. When I plot the graph, the order of dates for some reason are messed up. Inspite of specifying the category in the list, I am still not able to sort the problem. Here is what I tried:

I just have 4 time stamps as an example, but in the actual data, I have about 90000

```
time<-c("3/3/2020 6:09:30" , "3/3/2020 6:10:00" ,
        "3/3/2020 6:10:30" , "3/3/2020 6:11:00")
df<-data.frame("time"= time, "data"=rnorm(90000))

ay <- list(
    tickfont = list(size=20,color="blue"),
    titlefont = list(size=20,color="blue"),
    overlaying = "n",
    side = "left",
)

ax <- list(
    type = "category",
    categoryorder = "category ascending",
    categoryarray = unique(df$time),
    showgrid = TRUE,
    showline = TRUE,
    autorange = TRUE,
    showticklabels = TRUE,
    ticks = "outside",
    tickangle = 90
    )

fig <- plot_ly()%>%
  add_lines(data=df,x = ~time, y = ~data,line = list(color="blue"))%>%
  layout(yaxis=ay,xaxis = ax,hoverlabel = list(font=list(size=20)))
```

Comment: Those aren't dates or timestamps, those are strings. Does `plotly` know to infer datatypes when you send it something that might be a timestamp?

Comment: Is this link helpful? https://plotly.com/r/time-series/

Comment: Ya I agree, those a re strings. But why is not plotting in order? I want the x axis to be from string 1 to string 90k with no jumbling

Comment: ACE, I don't understand. You have four distinct points on the x-axis, corresponding with the four sorted strings. What about it is not plotting in order? 25% of the random points should be above the first x-axis string, 25% over the second string, etc. There is nothing that should be strewn or distributed across the x-axis.

Comment: @r2evans Sorry for the confusion. I've just shown 4 time stamps. There are 90k time stamps that continue like the one I showed for about a month . So the 5th time stamp would be "03/03/2020 6:11:30" and so on. Each of the 90k time stamps are unique. As you mentioned before, those arn't actually timestamps, but characters. The thing is some of those characters are being plotted at the end of the graph , and not in order.  I am guessing  ordering issues would be from having  time stamps as categorical instead of datetime. So I tried  converting it datetime using lubridate::dmy_hms(df$time) works